# How to update one instance of xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two versions of xcode running in company mac book pro:1)xcode 6.4 and 2)xcode 7.0.
I am pretty new to working with mac and am trying to learn programming ios applications with swift.
I want to updte xcode 2 (version 7.0) to version 7.2.

[image]

Now, my manager told me not to mess around with xcode 6.4 and not
to update the same as current codebases are managed with xcode 6.4.
How can I update just xcode 2 to latest version if it is possible at all ?
Or Do I have to download the .dmg file for the latest xcode from apple's website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to update through the regular way (App Store) it will not work since you will get the latest version. I would suggest that you download the version you want from the developer download [page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and make a new installation of the older version that way.